# Populate block of codes based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php

I am beginner in php, javascript coading. I am working on a project where I need the code to work like;

(radio buttons) Category: Size, quantity, weight

based on any one of this radio button selection, populate input tags field, where user can input tags relevant to the category selected
and after that based on number of input tags, ask for entering the prices for each tag.

Overview:

Category list Size, Quantity, Weight.

If category is size
then input tag 5cm, 10cm, 50cm, ....

Price for each tags
and this all details need to be stored in the database.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sold in</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-default" data-toggle-class="btn-primary" data-toggle-passive-class="btn-default">
   <input type="radio" name="sold_in" value="size" onclick="#size"> &nbsp; Size &nbsp;
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default" data-toggle-class="btn-primary" data-toggle-passive-class="btn-default">
   <input type="radio" name="sold_in" value="quantity"  checked="checked"> Quantity
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default" data-toggle-class="btn-primary" data-toggle-passive-class="btn-default">
   <input type="radio" name="sold_in" value="weight"> Weight
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" id="size">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input Tags</label>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <input id="tags_1" type="text" class="tags form-control" name="tags" placeholder="Size1 Size2" value="" data-role="tagsinput" />
  <div id="suggestions-container" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 250px; margin: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: So the html you've shown, if you were to wrap it in a `<form>` tag, would seem to cover the data entry part of your requirement. Then PHP can be used to store the data in a database. I'm not sure what you think you need JS for. Please be more specific.

Comment: Please format your code for readability and to eliminate scrolling.

Comment: Maybe JS required to call any function. I have seen JS in other related post. I am a beginner so do not have much idea